# On Interior and closure under Topology

Tags: general-topology

Supposing $A$ and $B$ are subsets of the topological space $X$, $C$ is a closed set in $X$, and $A$ belongs to $C$, then prove that $\text{cl}(A)$ belongs to $C$.

Comment: What is your definition of the closure of $A$?  There are several equivalent definitions.

Comment: One doesnt' say "$A $ belongs to $C$'. The correct terminology is $A$ is contained in $C$ or $A$ is a subset of $C$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take the following definition of the closure : the closure of $D$, noted $\overline{D}$, is the smallest (for the inclusion) closed set that contains $D$.

Here, you have $A\subset C$, so that $C$ is a closed set that contains $A$. Therefore, $\overline{A}\subset C$.